# Showing that these two statements about continuous functions almost everywhere are false

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

1. If $f$ : $\mathbb{R}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R}$ is almost everywhere continuous then there is a continuous function $g$ : $\mathbb{R}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)$ = $g(x)$ almost everywhere.

I believe the statement is false,
$f$ is said to be continuous almost everywhere if there is a Lebesgue measurable set E with $\lambda$($E^c$) = 0 such that $f$ is continuous at each point in E.

How would I show it is false.

2. Then also how would I show the statement: if If $g$ : $\mathbb{R}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f$ = $g$    $\lambda$-almost everywhere then $f$ is continuous almost everywhere. is false.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: 1, $f(x)=0$ for $x <0, 1$ for $x \geq 0$. 2. $f(x)=1$ for $x$ rational, $0$ for $x$ irrational.